# FileHelpers supports Hierarchical files?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, hierarchical-data, sourceforge, filehelpers

excuse-me if my english is bad... I'm Brazilian.

FileHelpers supports Hierarchical files?

I work with flat files, that have hierarchical records.
I don't found this feature in documentation.

Thanks!
Allan

Comment: what language? Which FileHelpers? Show a simple example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the MasterDatail way if two levels, or the MultirecordEngine if you need to parse three or more record formats.

**Master Detail:**

http://www.filehelpers.net/example/MasterDetail/SimpleMasterDetail/

For this file with customers as master record and orders as detail:

```
10248|VINET|5|04071996|01081996|16071996|3|32.38 
10249|TOMSP|6|05071996|16081996|10071996|1|11.61 
ALFKI;Alfreds Futterkiste;Maria Anders;Sales Representative;Obere Str. 57;Berlin;Germany 
ANATR;Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados;Ana Trujillo;Owner;Avda. de la Constitución 2222;México D.F.;Mexico 
10250|HANAR|4|08071996|05081996|12071996|2|65.83 
10111314012345 
11101314123456
```

You must use something like:

```
RecordAction ExampleSelector(string record)
{
   if (Char.IsLetter(record[0]))
      return RecordAction.Master;
   else
      return RecordAction.Detail;
}

var engine = new MasterDetailEngine<Customers, Orders>(new MasterDetailSelector(ExampleSelector));

// to Read use:
MasterDetails[] res = engine.ReadFile("TestIn.txt");
```

**Multirecord**

http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordSample/

Regards